# clarification on chrome extension local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am writing an app that starts by instantiating some blank starter data for a graph into the chrome.storage, as the extension is being used the data is updated.

The way I formatted the code right now is that the storage is instantiated when the code starts, which is a problem because the code starts over when you restart chrome so it overwrites all the data that has been written.

So I *think* I need to write in some sort of checking function where I can write something like

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function (result){
    if ("data" !== null){
        initStorage();
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

Is this the correct way to go about fixing this issue? 
I'm wondering if this works with how the storage functions? Does each extension have it's own storage area so there won't be anything there if I haven't saved anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can provide default values in `get`:

```
var default_data = { /* something */ };
chrome.storage.sync.get({data: default_data}, function(result) {
    // If "data" wasn't present in storage, result.data is a copy of default_data
    // Otherwise, result.data is a copy of the actual stored value
    chrome.storage.sync.set(result); // To save the default, if not saved
});
```

Comment: so this is the equivalent of checking if data exists, then writing the default data if not and retrieving existing data if it's there?

Comment: Yes. If the data was here and you didn't change `result`, the `set` will not change anything; if it was not there, you'll get the default and `set` will write it to the storage. I would put this code somewhere like `runtime.onStartup`.

Comment: really helpful tip

Answer (score 1):

Because you can retrieve multiple values from storage, `result` is an object with the keys you requested. Check if "data" exists in that object:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(result) {
    if (!("data" in result)) {
        initStorage();
    }
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: if I've only saved one key called data into storage from my extension, does it follow that if I haven't saved anything there would be nothing there? I'm not totally sure how the storage works like is there just one big bucket for everything using the storage or does each thing have it's own separate area to save keys into?

Comment: @Jessie Storage is one big bucket that you query. If you asked for `"data"`, it'll be only `result.data` (if it exists, or empty otherwise). If you asked for `["data", "somthing"]`, you'll get an object with at most 2 keys. If you ask for `null`, it'll dump the whole bucket.